# Woocommerce - dont add to cart product from another category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I have several categories and I'm trying to make it so that some categories cannot be added to the cart along with others. (when adding, there should be a redirect to the product and an error message is displayed).

I found the code that helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189297/prevent-add-to-cart-if-cart-contains-a-specific-category-woocommerce), but I couldn't edit it correctly so that the rule would apply to other categories

The problem is this
The categories below can be added to the cart among themselves
cheese
cheese-sets
bread
bakery
milk
Whereas the following categories should not be mixed with the categories above and among themselves
glamp
horse
foodtruck
other
farm

original code from link

```
<?php
//*** Prevent mixture of paint and other prods in same cart ***//
function dont_add_paint_to_cart_containing_other($validation, $product_id) {

// Set flag false until we find a product in cat paint
    $cart_has_paint = false;

// Set $cat_check true if a cart item is in paint cat
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {

        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if (has_term('paint', 'product_cat', $product->id)) {
            $cart_has_paint = true;
            // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
            break;
        }
    }

    $product_is_paint = false;
    if (has_term('paint', 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
        $product_is_paint = true;
    }

// Return true if cart empty
    if (!WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0) {
        // If cart contains paint and product to be added is not paint, display error message and return false.
        if ($cart_has_paint && !$product_is_paint) {
            wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase paint products on their own. To purchase this product, please checkout your current cart or empty your cart and try again', 'error');
            $validation = false;
        }
        // If cart contains a product that is not paint and product to be added is paint, display error message and return false.
        elseif (!$cart_has_paint && $product_is_paint) {
            wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase paint products on their own. To purchase this product, please checkout your current cart or empty your cart and try again', 'error');
            $validation = false;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise, return true.
    return $validation;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dont_add_paint_to_cart_containing_other', 10, 2);
?>
```

And reworked but not worked ^)
When "allowed" category in cart and i add any "prohibited" categoru its worked
But when i try add product from glamp and horse not worked? both product goes to cart andd rule not work

```
<?php
//*** Prevent mixture of certain categories in same cart ***//
function dont_add_categories_to_cart_containing_other($validation, $product_id) {
    // Set flag false until we find a product in prohibited categories
    $cart_has_prohibited = false;
    // Prohibited categories
    $prohibited_categories = array(
        'glamp',
        'horse',
        'foodtruck',
        'other',
        'farm'
    );
    // Allowed categories
    $allowed_categories = array(
        'cheese',
        'cheese-sets',
        'bread',
        'bakery',
        'milk'
    );

    // Set $cat_check true if a cart item is in prohibited categories
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "slugs"));
        $intersect_categories = array_intersect($prohibited_categories, $product_categories);

        if (!empty($intersect_categories)) {
            $cart_has_prohibited = true;
            // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
            break;
        }
    }

    $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "slugs"));
    $intersect_categories = array_intersect($prohibited_categories, $product_categories);
    $product_is_prohibited = !empty($intersect_categories);

    // Return true if cart empty
    if (!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        // If cart contains prohibited categories and product to be added is not prohibited, display error message and return false.
        if ($cart_has_prohibited && !$product_is_prohibited) {
            wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories. Please checkout your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
            $validation = false;
        }
        // If cart contains a product that is not prohibited and product to be added is from the prohibited categories, display error message and return false.
        elseif (!$cart_has_prohibited && $product_is_prohibited) {
            wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories. Please checkout your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
            $validation = false;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise, return true.
    return $validation;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dont_add_categories_to_cart_containing_other', 10, 2);
?>
```

Help solve the problem

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `$prohibited_categories` also only allows one product from those categories?

Comment: Can you put possible cases to your question about which should allow and which not?

Comment: If I add cheese and milk to the basket, for example, and then add a horse, everything will work, I will not be able to add a horse, I will get a redirect to the product page with the message "Sorry, you can only buy, etc...."

But when I add an item from the "prohibited" category to the cart, such as horses and farms, they are added to the cart,
I tried to make it so that they could not be added either, a redirect appeared and a message saying that you cannot add this product to the cart together...

Comment: I have 10 categories in total, 
Еhe first five should be combined with each other but should not be combined with others : cheese, cheese-sets, bread bakery, milk.

The other 5 should not be combined with any categories, they can be added to the cart only 1 from each category (otherwise a redirect and a message that this is not possible) : glamp, horse, foodtruck, other, farm.

Comment: Let's say the cart is empty. Then should product allowed from `$prohibited_categories`?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you have `added cheese and milk to the cart` but in the latest comment, you said that `they can be added to the cart only 1 from each category` can you confirm this, please?

Comment: they can be added to the cart only 1 from each category - its what i try to do but its not work

Comment: $prohibited_categories - I'm trying to make it so that they can't be added together

Comment: Let's say the cart is empty. Then should product allowed from $prohibited_categories? - yes but only one category example horse or farm,

Comment: Can you add cases to your question like if the user tries product from `prohibited_categories` should allow or not?  if the user tries a product from `allowed_categories ` should allow or not. if the user tries a product from `prohibited_categories` and `allowed_categories ` should allow or not. etc...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: 1) We have empty cart - i add product from "allowed_categories" cheese, cheese-sets, bread, bakery, milk = 5 products from 5 different category in cart - it works with a code.

Comment: 2) We have 5 products from 5 different category in cart (allowed_categories) and i add 1 product from "prohibited_categories" example horse - the product dont added, after redirect on product page and i see msg (Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories.) - it works with a code.

Comment: 3) We have empty cart - i add one product from one "prohibited_categories" example horse and after add product from "allowed_categories" cheese - the product (cheese) dont added, after redirect on product page and i see msg (Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories.) - it works with a code.

Comment: 4) We have empty cart - i add one product from one "prohibited_categories" example horse and 1 more prduct from another "prohibited_categories" example farm, the product (farm) dont added, after redirect on product page and i see msg (Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories.) - it not works with code.

Comment: "allowed_categories" allowed together in cart - it works with a code
"allowed_categories" + "prohibited_categories" not allowed in cart (redirect+msg) - it works with a code
"prohibited_categories" + "allowed_categories" not allowed in cart (redirect+msg) - it works with a code
"prohibited_categories" horse + "prohibited_categories" foodtruck not allowed in cart (redirect+msg) - it NO works with a code

Comment: 1) We have empty cart - i add product from "allowed_categories" cheese, cheese-sets, bread, bakery, milk = 5 products from 5 different category in cart - it works with a code. 
=> Should the user allow to add more products from the same category if the user already added a cheese category product then should allowed again they can add the cheese category product?

Comment: Should the user allow to add more products from the same category if the user already added a cheese category product then should allowed again they can add the cheese category product? = > yes - any poductt any qty from any allowed_categories

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above discussion. I have added logic. try the below code.

```
//*** Prevent mixture of certain categories in same cart ***//
function dont_add_categories_to_cart_containing_other($passed_validation, $product_id) {
    // Get the product categories
    $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "slugs"));

    // Prohibited categories
    $prohibited_categories = array(
        'glamp',
        'horse',
        'foodtruck',
        'other',
        'farm'
    );

    // Allowed categories
    $allowed_categories = array(
        'cheese',
        'cheese-sets',
        'bread',
        'bakery',
        'milk'
    );

    // Check if the product is in a prohibited category
    $product_is_prohibited = !empty(array_intersect($prohibited_categories, $product_categories));

    // Check if the product is in an allowed category
    $product_is_allowed = !empty(array_intersect($allowed_categories, $product_categories));

    // Check if there are any prohibited products in the cart
    $cart_has_prohibited = false;
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $cart_product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($cart_product_id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "slugs"));

        if (!empty(array_intersect($prohibited_categories, $cart_product_categories))) {
            $cart_has_prohibited = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check if the cart has any allowed products
    $cart_has_allowed = false;
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $cart_product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($cart_product_id, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "slugs"));

        if (!empty(array_intersect($allowed_categories, $cart_product_categories))) {
            $cart_has_allowed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Return true if cart is empty
    if (WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        return $passed_validation;
    }
    

    // If cart contains prohibited products and the product to be added is not prohibited, display error message and return false.
    if ($cart_has_prohibited && !$product_is_prohibited) {
        wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories. Please review your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
        return false;
    }

    // If cart contains prohibited products and the product to be added is prohibited, display error message and return false.
    if ($cart_has_prohibited && $product_is_prohibited) {
        wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase products from the allowed categories. Please review your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
        return false;
    }

    // If cart contains an allowed product and the product to be added is prohibited, display error message and return false.
    if ($cart_has_allowed && $product_is_prohibited) {
        wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase one product from the prohibited categories. Please review your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
        return false;
    }

    /*// If cart contains an allowed product and the product to be added is also allowed, display error message and return false.
    if ($cart_has_allowed && $product_is_allowed) {
        wc_add_notice('Sorry, you can only purchase one product from each category. Please review your current cart or empty your cart and try again.', 'error');
        return false;
    }*/

    return $passed_validation;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dont_add_categories_to_cart_containing_other', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks but can you help more little "product_is_prohibited" example @foodtruck@ category, when i add 1 prdouct it ok but now i cant add one more from same category
need block add to cart not product from same category,

Comment: foodtruck
prdouct-1 product-2 product-3 etc can be added in cart together

But if we have different cat the cant be added together
example - product-1 (foodtruck) product-1(horse)

Answer (score 0):

Bhautik thank you for your help your questions and your help motivated me more than ever. I found another option that eventually works for me.

```
<?php
    function custom_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
        // Get the product categories
        $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
    
        // Creating a list of prohibited combinations of categories
        $prohibited_combinations = array(
            array( 'category-c', 'category-a' ),
            array( 'category-c', 'category-b' ),
            array( 'category-d', 'category-a' ),
            array( 'category-d', 'category-b' ),
        );
    
        // Check whether the selected product is in the basket
        if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $cart_item_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                $cart_item_product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item_product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
    
                // Checking prohibited combinations
                foreach ( $prohibited_combinations as $combination ) {
                    if ( in_array( $combination[0], $product_categories ) && in_array( $combination[1], $cart_item_product_categories ) ) {
                        // If a forbidden combination is found, we output an error message
                        wc_add_notice( 'You cannot add products from these categories together to the cart.', 'error' );
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $passed;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
?>
```